# Microservices architecture database

Tags: database, microservices

I have been studying microservice architecture for a while. But I have a few questions on my mind.

If you need to give an example, they are
order-service
customer-service
Product-service

Suppose there are 3 microservices above. They are using relational databases.

I list orders in the order-service. But I also have to pull customer informations here.

If this were a monolotic structure, I could handle it with join. But how can I do that in microservis architecture.

Note: I’m not doing any projects. My goal is only to understand the microservice architecture.

Answer (score 1):

Options:

- Limit the dependency between orderservice and customerservice: normaly the order is a self containing object that has all the customers data (from the time of ordering) in it.
- If still needed the order should have the id of the customer saved and then any UI or logic that want to access recent customer data need to use the "public api" of the customer service. The "public api" in general can be anything - it even can be a defined shared storage (like a database). However most teams decide to not allow direct access to the technical storage to avoid tight coupling. Thats why most of the times service talk Rest (or GRPC) for syncronous use cases or use some form of messaging for async interactions

However - decide why you want to split it up - are you expecting a growing developer base and high complexity? If not a monolith might be cheaper to build for your case..

Answer (score 0):

> But how can I do that in microservis architecture.

Just by calling another microservice and asking for required additional information.

Normally microservices do not share database, as you noticed.

So if you have a class `Order` like that

```
class Order
{
    OrderId;
    ItemName;
    UserName;
}
```

And a method that returns an order `GetOrder(id)` like that

```
GetOrder(orderId)
{
    item = ItemMicroserice.GetItem();
    user = UserMicroservice.GetUser();

    result = new Order()
    {
        OrderId = orderId,
        ItemName = item.Name,
        UserName = user.Name
    }

    return result;
}
```

You can notice that there are two calls to other microservices that will return data to construct `Order` object.

Thought you can see that it can be slightly not optimal in sense of performance. So sometimes microservices do store duplicate information to be able to construct objects faster (eliminate calls to other microservices). And, for example, if `Users` microservice updates data, it sends an event to `Orders` microservice so it can update cached data from other microservices.